# Добавить параметр в корзину при добавлении товара в нее

Tags: битрикс

Всем привет.

Есть интернет магазин на Битриксе.

Подскажите, как можно сделать передачу дополнительного параметра в корзину, когда пользователь кликает на кнопку "купить"?
Сейчас у меня такая ссылка на кнопку: `href="?action=ADD2BASKET&id=<?=$arResult["ID"]?>&kredit=yes&clear_cache=Y"`

Мне нужно чтобы параметр "`kredit=yes`" уже как то обозначался в корзине товаров и я мог бы выделить этот товар. Где обрабатывается `action=ADD2BASKET` и как добавить параметр в массив `$arResult["ITEMS"]["AnDelCanBuy"]` компонента корзины?

Comment: Решил. Использовал метод CSaleBasket::Add($arFields); При клике добавляется новый товар в корзину и обновляется если он уже есть. А дополнительный параметр записал в ключ "NOTES" массива $arFields.

Comment: Аккуратно, там какие-то подводные камни есть. Я перед добавлением в корзину удалял этот элемент, а потом добавлял. Иначе, если у тебя в корзине уже есть этот товар, то к уже добавленному количеству просто добавляется еще 1 (то есть, просто меняется количество).